# Injecting $http service into $get to use within anonymous function

Tags: angularjs, anonymous-function

I am trying to inject $http into the $get of my provider to use within a function that is being created dynamically.  It builds the function and my controller successfully calls the function, but while inside the function created, it errors saying `$http is not defined`.  Is there another way to inject this dependency to make it available?

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app').provider('rest', rest);

    function rest(){
        endpointObjs = [];
        return {

            addEndpoint:function(name, request, endpoint){
                obj = {};
                obj.name = name;
                obj.request = request;
                obj.endpoint = endpoint;
                endpointObjs.push(obj);

            },
            $get:['$http', function($http){

                endpoints = [];
                for(i=0;i<endpointObjs.length;i++){
                    endpoints[endpointObjs[i].name] = new Function("return $http({ url:'" + endpointObjs[i].endpoint + "', method:'" + endpointObjs[i].request + "'});")
                }

                return {endpoints:endpoints};
            }]
        };
    }
})();
```

EDIT:

My end goal is to create a provider that allows someone to configure all of their rest endpoints in the config for the app and then they can inject the provider into their controller and call the autogenerated function that they defined in the config ie.

config.js
`restProvider.addEndpoint("allSoftware", "GET", "software/all");`

controller.js
`rest.endpoints.allSoftware().then(function(data){....});`

Comment: It's because that's not an anonymous function; it's a function being parsed from a string, which is pretty much equivalent to `eval`. Why not actually create an anonymous function, like `= function () { return $http({ url: ...`?

Comment: Creating a function in that way is not suitable for what I am trying to achieve.  I need to to be more dynamic than that will allow.  The interesting thing is, when I change to : 

`new Function("return " + $http + "({ url:'" + endpointObjs[i].endpoint + "', method:'" + endpointObjs[i].request + "', params:'" + endpointObjs[i].params + "'});")`

I get a different error `isObject` is not defined.  It is actually calling the $http function at this point but cannot reach angular's isObject function apparently

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include how you're using this, because I do believe you can do this in a manner similar to how I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Functions created by `new Function` do not create closures bound to their creation context; they always are created in the global scope.

Instead, use a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

```
$get:['$http', function($http){

    endpoints = [];
    for(let i=0;i<endpointObjs.length;i++){
        let config = {
            url: endpointObjs[i].endpoint,
            method: endpointsObj[i].request
        };
        let fn = function() { return $http(config) };
        endpoints[endpointObjs[i].name] = fn;
    };

    return {endpoints:endpoints};
}]
```

As well as being able to create closures bound to their creation context, function expressions are more efficient as they are parsed with the rest of the code.

---

> So eventually I would like this to allow for parameters to be passed from the controller

Then add a `params` argument to the function expression:

```
 let fn = function(params) {
      if (params) {
          config.params = params;
      }; 
      return $http(config);
 };
```

Comment: So eventually I would like this to allow for parameters to be passed from the controller implementing the service.  Using this method of dynamic function creation, how would I provide that functionality since everything is enclosed within `config` would I be able to do `$http(config, params:{})`?